# Have "ls" return subdirectory in results?

Tags: ls

Simplified situation: I'm located in `~`. There is a folder `~/folder` and inside, there are many, many, many `.txt` files named `1.txt`, `2.txt`, etc.

I want to generate a `file_list.txt` inside of `~` whose contents are:

```
folder/1.txt
folder/2.txt
etc...
```

If I do

```
ls folder>file_list.txt
```

I get

```
1.txt
2.txt
etc.
```

How do I get the folder to be listed as well? I've just been doing a workaround loop in python but that's a bit slow when the number of files I have is this large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need `ls` for this, the shell’s own globbing will do what you’re after:

```
printf "%s\n" folder/* > file_list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `find` looking for all the "regular" (not directories, devices, etc)

```
find folder -type f > file_list.txt
```

Comment: With just `ls` you can use `ls -R` or `ls -r` if you don't want all the sub directories.